# how to update a specific property in a state using ngrx

Tags: ngrx, effects

how do i update a specific property of object in a state?

[image]

i need to update the property offerPrice but still want to retain the other state values in the object

this is what i have in my effects

```
case OffersActionTypes.SET_TOTAL_OFFER_PRICE:
        return { 
            ...state, offerDetails: {
                ...state, singleOfferDetails: [
                    ...state.offerPrice, action.payload
            ]
        }}
```

but on the redux tools it giving me this

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more code? How is the action written, how is it dispatched and with what payload?

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, you're not copying the parts of state that need to be copied. I believe you want something more like:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  offerDetails: {
    ...state.offerDetails,
    singleOfferDetails: {
      ...state.offerDetails.singleOfferDetails,
      offerPrice: action.payload
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this can also be achieved with something like:

```js
const newState = { ...state };
newState.offerDetails.singleOfferDetails.offerPrice = action.payload;
return newState;
```

I would argue, however, that your store is too embedded. Generally you want to keep things as flat as possible, although I'll grant you that it's not always a simple process. Best of luck!